# How to convert a json of objects to dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have a json like this :

```
[
  {
    "id" : 887,
    "title" : "ماه نو",
    "voice_actor" : "ع. پاشایی",
    "compiler" : "رابیندرانات تاگور",
    "cover_image" : "d5c446a1d81340d2bb912d51b00a3d79"
  },
  {
    "id" : 607,
    "title" : "حکایت آن که دلسرد نشد (درس هایی برای رسیدن به موفقیت و ثروت)",
    "voice_actor" : "حمید محمدی",
    "compiler" : "مارک فیشر",
    "cover_image" : "26ead648b33e4977805c7e979f8cc78c"
  }
]
```

now I would like to convert it to a dictionary like this :

```
key:value
```

in this case the `key` is arbitrary (an unique Int) and `value` is objects.

I wanted to use this function but it returns nil :

```
 func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }    

 let value = self.convertToDictionary(text: abovejson)
 //value is null
```

---

**updated**

I want to use @Nirav D answer but I got an error :

```
   func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] as? []
                var dictionary = [Int:Any]()
                //Loop through array and set object in dictionary
                for (index,item) in array.enumerated() {
                    let uniqueID = index //Or generate uniqued Int id
                    dictionary[uniqueID] = item
                }
            }
            catch {}
        }
        return nil
    }


Expected element type for as? []
```

[image]

Comment: you can create a model class of your data.Then parse your json and get your values and pass them to model object and append in  array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `JSON` response with Top level as `Array` not `dictionary`. So you need to cast it to `[[String:Any]]` instead of `[String: Any]`.

Now if you want to convert this `Array` response to `Dictionary` with type `[Int:Any]` then you need to loop through the array and make dictionary from it.

```
do {
     let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
     var dictionary = [Int:Any]()
     //Loop through array and set object in dictionary
     for (index,item) in array.enumerated() {
         let uniqueID = index //Or generate uniqued Int id 
         dictionary[uniqueID] = item
     }
}
catch {}
```

Comment: I got this message: `Expected element type` for `as? []`

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Edit your question with your current try and also show where you are getting this error.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian It is typo mistake at the end instead of `as? []` it should be `?? []` I have also edited my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to convert your JSON String to NSData by doing the following

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then simply use the JSONObjectWithData method to convert it to JSON object

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: @KrishnaCA nothing wrong with my answer, the return type in my case is an id. The asker json response is an array of dictionary. So the asker should either cast it to `[AnyObject]` or if he's intending to try objective-c use `id`

Comment: Please include the explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SwiftyJSON which makes it easy to convert and access with JSON data in Swift.

```
// A Simple sample
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}
```

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score -2):

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
return nil
```

}

let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"

let dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)

swift 2

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    do {
        return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
return nil
 }

 let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"

  let result = convertStringToDictionary(str)
```